# ¿Cómo actualizar referencia a servicio en WCF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

estoy aprendiendo a realizar servicios y clientes en WCF, y tras haber creado el cliente he añadido nuevos métodos en el servicio, sin emabargo, no encuentro el modo de actualizar la referencia en el cliente, he visto en otros Posts que seleccionan la opción de actualizar referencia en el solution explorer pero en mi caso no aparece.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado: En el wizard de servicios conectados, escogemos el que queramos actualizar, tres puntos de la derecha, editar, y completamos el proceso. Se actualizará.